# Nested loops in SQL Server, with results from stored procedures feeding nested stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, loops

I've worked with databases for a while but haven't ever needed to do something like this.

Background - I've plugged SQL Server into the back of several apps via linked server. There's no documentation about the db-insides of these applications.

I'd like to record meta-data about each linked server. The approach I was thinking is something like this:

(note `sp_columns` doesn't work on these linked servers)

**Step 1**

sp_linkedservers (to get list of linked servers using some criteria)

-> sp_tables_ex (to get list of tables)

--> create temp tables based on table names (insert into ...)

**Step 2**

loop through temp tables, and for each table

--> sp_columns and write output to final destination table which will record linked server, table, column, type...

This pseudo-system table can can searched when looking for meta-data about the linked servers columns.

What is the SQL Server way of approaching this problem?

**EDIT**: I should add the linked servers are Firebird and Progress databases accessed with ODBC connections.

Comment: If you can describe where exactly is the problem, I can help and post the answer. There are multiple ways to get metadata ,e.g. you can read system tables directly on each linked server.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the content of and relationships between tables within a linked db.

Answer (score 1):

If your work is to record tablename, column name, column types of each linked servers then i guess you can work with this.

```
DECLARE @SERVER VARCHAR(100),@QUERY VARCHAR(MAX),@DBASE VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @DBNAME TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),DBASE VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @TABLES TABLE (SERVERNAME VARCHAR(100),DBNAME VARCHAR(100),[SCHEMA] VARCHAR(100),[TABLE] VARCHAR(100),[COLUMN] VARCHAR(100),DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
SELECT quotename(srvname) FROM MASTER.SYS.sysservers WHERE SRVID>0 AND providername='SQLOLEDB'
OPEN C 
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SERVER
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN


    SET @QUERY='EXEC (''SELECT name FROM SYS.databases WHERE owner_sid>1'') AT '+@SERVER+' '
    INSERT INTO @DBNAME EXEC (@QUERY)
    DECLARE D CURSOR FOR
    SELECT QUOTENAME(DBASE) FROM @DBNAME
    OPEN D
    FETCH NEXT FROM D INTO @DBASE
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        SET @QUERY='EXEC (''USE '+@DBASE+';
            SELECT @@SERVERNAME,TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'') AT '+@SERVER+' '
        INSERT INTO @TABLES EXEC (@QUERY)
    FETCH NEXT FROM D INTO @DBASE
    END
    CLOSE D
    DEALLOCATE D

DELETE FROM @DBNAME
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @SERVER
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C

SELECT * FROM @TABLES
```

Comment: I like it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ranjana. The linked servers unfortunately don't support RPC, and so can't be queried in this way. It's given me a starting point though.

Comment: You need to configure RPC in linked server properties.

Comment: Hi Ranjana. RPC enabled. Errors out querying 'name from sys.database ... at linked server. Cannot execute statement on remote server. I've tried variations on that query each with the same result. Your code has given me a starting point for an alternative. Thanks again.